# How to get a proper filepath of Tempfile in Rails when seeing "Getting Errno::ENOENT ' no such file or directory @ rb_sysopen'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, docsplit

I want to show a preview of presentation files on my website. I am trying to make a tempfile which reads from a Microsoft PowerPoint Open XML (`.pptx`) file stored in active storage.

I am using `Docsplit.extract_images` on the tempfile to convert the slides to images to show it as a preview in some form of image carousel.

I have slide parameterss such as `[:name, :ppt, pages: [] ]` where `ppt` is `has_one_attached` and pages is `has_many_attached`. This is what my slides_controller look like:

```
def create
    @slide = Slide.new(slide_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @slide.save
        tempfile = Tempfile.new([ 'foobar', '.pptx'])
        tempfile.binmode

        begin
          @slide.ppt.download { |chunk| tempfile.write(chunk) }
          tempfile.flush
          tempfile.rewind
        ensure
          tempfile.close!
        end
        @slide.pages << Docsplit.extract_images("#{tempfile.path}", :size => '1080x', :format => [:png])
        tempfile.unlink

        format.html { redirect_to slide_url(@slide), notice: "Slide was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @slide }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @slide.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I am getting a `Errno::ENOENT no such file or directory @ rb_sysopen` error.

Is this the correct way to get the `tempfile` path?

Also, If I use `tempfile.path` instead of `"#{tempfile.path}"`, I get a nil to string error.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You did a pretty good job asking your question, but I'd recommend removing the final question and asking it separately. It's not closely related to the main question and could cause downvotes or close votes because of forcing the question to be too broad. Also, please flesh out your code so it's runnable; See [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ensure you are using tempfile.close! this unlinks the file per https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#method-i-close-21

If you just use close without the bang (!) then you should be all set!